# Button does not call function

Tags: javascript

So, i was trying to make a game as [Candybox](http://candies.aniwey.net/). I do create a button which gets the onclick-attribute to call a function.

```
if (AnzahlTP === 10)
                    {
                        var para = document.createElement("button");
                        var node = document.createTextNode("Treuepunkte verschenken");
                        para.appendChild(node);

                        var element = document.getElementById("haupt-div");
                        element.appendChild(para);

                        var b1 = document.getElementsByTagName("button")[1]; //gibt dem Knopf eine Funktion
                        var att = document.createAttribute("onclick");

                        att.value = "TPVerschenken()";
                        b1.setAttributeNode(att);
                    }
```

The Button should call this function, which will print something into a p-Tag at the Top.

```
function TPVerschenken()
        {
            AnzahlTPV = AnzahlTPV + AnzahlTP;
            document.getElementById("TPVDisplay").innerHTML = "Verschenkte Treuepunkte: " + AnzahlVTP;
            AnzahlTP = 0;
        }
```

But if the button is pressed, the function doesnt work, or isn't called. I checked that the onclick-attribute is given to the button.

Here the whole code, if it's needed.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="spiel.css"/>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Test, I guess...</title>
</head>
<body id="body">
    <div id="nav">

    </div>

    <div id="haupt-div">
        <p id="TPDisplay"></p>
        <p id="TPVDisplay"></p>
        <button id="Knopf" onclick="TPSammelnKnopf()">
            Anfangen Treuepunkte zu sammeln
        </button>
        <script>
            var TPSammeln = false; //Deklaration von Variablen am Anfang
            var AnzahlTP = 0;
            var AnzahlTPV = 0;

            function TPSammelnKnopf()
            {
                if (!TPSammeln)
                {
                    AnzahlTP++;
                    document.getElementById("TPDisplay").innerHTML = "Treuepunkte: " + AnzahlTP; //Damit dort direkt Text steht und er nicht erst erscheinen muss.

                    setInterval(function()
                    {
                        AnzahlTP++;
                        document.getElementById("TPDisplay").innerHTML = "Treuepunkte: " + AnzahlTP;

                        if (AnzahlTP === 10)
                        {
                            var para = document.createElement("button");
                            var node = document.createTextNode("Treuepunkte verschenken");
                            para.appendChild(node);

                            var element = document.getElementById("haupt-div");
                            element.appendChild(para);

                            var b1 = document.getElementsByTagName("button")[1]; //gibt dem Knopf eine Funktion
                            var att = document.createAttribute("onclick");

                            att.value = "TPVerschenken()";
                            b1.setAttributeNode(att);
                        }

                        if (AnzahlTP === 80)
                        {
                            var para = document.createElement("button");
                            var node = document.createTextNode("Shop freischalten");
                            para.appendChild(node);

                            var element = document.getElementById("haupt-div");
                            element.appendChild(para);

                            var b2 = document.getElementsByTagName("button")[2]; //gibt dem Knopf eine Funktion
                            var att = document.createAttribute("onclick");

                            att.value = "Shop()";
                            b2.setAttributeNode(att);
                        }

                    }, 1000);
                    TPSammeln = true;

                    var parent = document.getElementById("haupt-div");
                    var child = document.getElementById("Knopf");
                    parent.removeChild(child);
                }
            }

            function TPVerschenken()
            {
                AnzahlTPV = AnzahlTPV + AnzahlTP;
                document.getElementById("TPVDisplay").innerHTML = "Verschenkte Treuepunkte: " + AnzahlVTP;
                AnzahlTP = 0;
            }

            function Shop()
            {

            }
        </script>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Because `document.getElementsByTagName("button")[1]` returns `undefined`. Check the console for errors...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To set `onclick` event for the button you created from javascript code, you should do it like this:

```
para.onclick = (function () {
    return function () {
        TPVerschenken();
    };
})();
```

Or simpler, you can use:

```
para.addEventListener("click", TPVerschenken);
```

For the full tested code, please check [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/exb5q08z/).